# What do I put in my return if I want to return the response from an api call react?

Tags: reactjs, header, react-hooks, fetch, auth0

I needed to add headers to my api call.  I tried doing this many different ways to no avail.  This is my original api call without the header:

```
export default async function FetchPageMarkdown(page: string): Promise<string> {
    const baseUrl = getBackendUrl();
    let response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/pagemarkdown/${page}`);
    let text = await response.text();

    return text
}
```

This is how I am trying to add the header:

```
const FetchPageMarkdown = (page: string): Promise<string> => {

  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

  const callSecureApi = async () => {

    const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
    const baseUrl = getBackendUrl();
    const response = await fetch(
      `${baseUrl}/api/pagemarkdown/${page}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );

    const text = await response.text();
    return text;
  }

};

export default FetchPageMarkdown;
```

Without having a return I get a function whose declared type is neither 'void' nore 'any' must return a value.  I want to return the text coming from the api call which is markdown.  If I put the return outside the callSecureApi function it cannot find text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling and returning the result of the asynchronous function, i.e. `return callSecureApi();`?

Since `useAuth0` is a React hook it can't be called from functions (breaks rules of hooks), but its `getAccessTokenSilently` function can be passed around.

```
const fetchPageMarkdown = (getAccessTokenSilently: () => string, page: string): Promise<string> => {
  const callSecureApi = async () => {
    const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
    const baseUrl = getBackendUrl();
    const response = await fetch(
      `${baseUrl}/api/pagemarkdown/${page}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );

    const text = await response.text();
    return text;
  }

  return callSecureApi(); // invoke and return Promise
};
```

Usage:

```
const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

fetchPageMarkdown(getAccessTokenSilently, page)
  .then(text => {
    // handle returned text
  });
```

Comment: Yes, I am also getting an invalid hook call error. Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.  Instead of const FetchPageMarkdown I did function FetchPageMarkdown(page: string): Promise<string>

Comment: @dev_in_training Is `useAuth0` a React hook? If so then it needs to be moved to the body of the functional component and value passed to this function, or `FetchPageMarkdown` can be rewritten to be a custom hook.

Comment: yes useAuth0 is a React hook.  I thought my component FetchPageMarkdown was a functional component...

Comment: @dev_in_training `FetchPageMarkdown` looks to be a regular javascript function. I updated my answer and renamed it `fetchPageMarkdown` since it isn't a React component.